Expression evaluates numerically inside of Plot but not inside NIntegrate
I have a function that I want to integrate:
Tol[x_]:=If[x<$min\[Tau]l,$min\[Tau]l,x];
Q0int[r_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ,\[CapitalLambda]_?NumericQ,m\[Chi]_?NumericQ]:=fy[y]*((Exp[Map[Tol,-\[Tau]mf[r,y,\[CapitalLambda],m\[Chi]]]]+Exp[Map[Tol,-\[Tau]pf[r,y,\[CapitalLambda],m\[Chi]]]])/2);
Q0i[r_,\[CapitalLambda]_,m\[Chi]_]:=NIntegrate[Q0int[r,y,\[CapitalLambda],m\[Chi]],{y,\[Epsilon]reg2,1-\[Epsilon]reg2},Method->"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo",PrecisionGoal->$integralprecision,AccuracyGoal->$integralprecision,WorkingPrecision->$intprec,MaxPoints->$MaxPointsM];
$min\[Tau]l=-90;
fy[y_]:=y/Sqrt[1-y^2];

The 2 functions [Tau]mf and [Tau]pf are obtained through interpolation, and are usually quite smooth, but can take any positive value, and are lists (this is why I use Map).
Tol is used to be sure that the exponentials do not get an exponent that is too negative.
The function Q0int can plot without problems, but always gives error when I place it inside NIntegrate. The domain in both cases is {y,10^(-4),1-10^(-4)} to avoid the (integrable) singularities. Note that usually I solve this problem using NumericQ, but here does not work.
Trying to sample the function regularly and then interpolate and integrate reduces significantly the precision, and forces me to use >10^4 points, that considerably increases computation time. I also tried functioninterpolate but it returns a single value and not a list.
I made many attempts like using Evaluate, N and so on but none of them worked.
So far the best approach is making an ad-hoc sampling concentrated around y=1. This usually reduces by a factor of 10 the number of points required to achive a certain precision comparing to equally-spaces sampling. Still, I'd love to find a way to achive a reasonable precision without wasting too much computation time as I need to evaluate this 10^3 times or so...
I cannot provide the full interpolation tables for the 2 functions, but here is an example for some specific choices of the parameters r,CapitalLambda,mchi:
tabmf = {{1/
10000, {0.00010512123631685172`, 8.024312298448301`*^-12, 
 0.000013733286210085951`, 1.7096834259896014`*^-12, 
 608.119973018572`, 244.96596591263886`, 3.046449661936662`, 
 32.97925552576438`, 243.49622077240656`, 
 49.05680141322451`}}, {5009/
100000, {0.00010525136805895247`, 8.03424413913183`*^-12, 
 0.00001375029027186759`, 1.71179982234848`*^-12, 
 608.87308356769`, 245.2693896875493`, 3.050223224214362`, 
 33.02009659985603`, 243.79776811131262`, 
 49.11756619216698`}}, {1251/
12500, {0.0001056436062571646`, 8.064180283331156`*^-12, 
 0.000013801543349068757`, 1.7181789833153186`*^-12, 
 611.1430878448035`, 246.18396210569446`, 3.061597404709451`, 
 33.143198569740775`, 244.70668337994988`, 
 49.30072190967491`}}, {15007/
100000, {0.00010630683284457169`, 8.114798500630106`*^-12, 
 0.00001388820625787605`, 1.7289653562250565`*^-12, 
 614.9814093704575`, 247.73040498149612`, 3.080829920652378`, 
 33.35135004011033`, 246.24355638790786`, 
 49.610418478812754`}}, {10003/
50000, {0.0001072549445419021`, 8.187177851274859`*^-12, 
 0.000014012039252264068`, 1.7443840808276795`*^-12, 
 620.4622140159528`, 249.9368136382907`, 3.1082588500299346`, 
 33.6486372906407`, 248.43830656107062`, 
 50.05216430155709`}}, {5001/
20000, {0.00010851397246359887`, 8.283267679989002`*^-12, 
 0.000014176555803158212`, 1.76486021790117`*^-12, 
 627.748729978606`, 252.8725247232865`, 3.1447690855301924`, 
 34.043783838698275`, 251.35584521199436`, 
 50.640080253534975`}}, {7501/
25000, {0.00011011460344298208`, 8.405428037588517`*^-12, 
 0.000014385711190483483`, 1.7908919705818026`*^-12, 
 637.0124038824446`, 256.60485304803336`, 3.1911865898762373`, 
 34.546150667814004`, 255.06504038464277`, 
 51.38753030504012`}}, {35003/
100000, {0.00011210185153353259`, 8.557095054980798`*^-12, 
 0.000014645385214504041`, 1.823211396394634`*^-12, 
 648.513349626017`, 261.2384415701018`, 3.248811309477963`, 
 35.16985072199537`, 259.67006666190247`, 
 52.31545546603328`}}, {20001/
50000, {0.00011453403241217299`, 8.742711055603932`*^-12, 
 0.000014963214742852471`, 1.862766500584854`*^-12, 
 662.591298112435`, 266.91081079798795`, 3.319358970655591`, 
 35.93328030901673`, 265.3068585082191`, 
 53.451452763215364`}}, {45001/
100000, {0.00011749073900556142`, 8.968359653930551`*^-12, 
 0.000015349586400359783`, 1.9108525735376937`*^-12, 
 679.7048515483907`, 273.80614705662146`, 3.405114452988669`, 
 36.8613365438848`, 272.1591358012835`, 54.83234788593071`}}, {1/
2, {0.00012108187475416746`, 9.242421484100424`*^-12, 
 0.00001581887078494425`, 1.9692562287715266`*^-12, 
 700.4916488388662`, 282.1818288147855`, 3.509283926018303`, 
 37.988574629403146`, 280.4821278775813`, 
 56.509739155733286`}}, {54999/
100000, {0.00012546305859595868`, 9.57677293735527`*^-12, 
 0.000016391407955059226`, 2.040508773015707`*^-12, 
 725.8511773318984`, 292.3994306472418`, 3.6363518137356343`, 
 39.363824606779175`, 290.6361687448254`, 
 58.55590831063434`}}, {29999/
50000, {0.00013085042836958165`, 9.987901134751616`*^-12, 
 0.000017095453521975167`, 2.1281246179789126`*^-12, 
 757.0373521562298`, 304.9653980479612`, 3.79263159110373`, 
 41.055019870714986`, 303.12309910029717`, 
 61.07243441931056`}}, {64997/
100000, {0.00013757559773601858`, 1.0501099724490941`*^-11, 
 0.000017974372931100563`, 2.237496529622796`*^-12, 
 795.972025147083`, 320.6543107289285`, 3.9877537037143767`, 
 43.16638556002509`, 318.71244500143143`, 
 64.21440959939383`}}, {17499/
25000, {0.00014615402198910215`, 1.1155702566411657`*^-11, 
 0.000019095529401655044`, 2.377007355789652`*^-12, 
 845.6371065866892`, 340.6665306465182`, 4.236632919840279`, 
 45.85968871411034`, 338.5983738632227`, 
 68.22208048081731`}}, {14999/
20000, {0.00015742223428735658`, 1.2015485298199838`*^-11, 
 0.000020568380821314814`, 2.560259637292111`*^-12, 
 910.8911846240443`, 366.9639352864459`, 4.563697990954633`, 
 49.39824660965327`, 364.725709540854`, 
 73.48864892104847`}}, {39997/
50000, {0.00017294748462249232`, 1.3199963085230194`*^-11, 
 0.000022597894576126403`, 2.8127364012626673`*^-12, 
 1000.804758203593`, 403.19388980215257`, 5.01418932551344`, 
 54.27443251972868`, 400.7279744618224`, 
 80.74329505244175`}}, {84993/
100000, {0.00019583667238740662`, 1.4946051268502984`*^-11, 
 0.000025590506082229774`, 3.1849632044228697`*^-12, 
 1133.4278645846355`, 456.65262920963255`, 5.679084010936918`, 
 61.46598062680213`, 453.82857029841375`, 
 91.44965610073852`}}, {11249/
12500, {0.0002340202392360657`, 1.7858046433439775`*^-11, 
 0.00003058440104989408`, 3.8058764367713136`*^-12, 
 1354.8200282762507`, 545.9182373824374`, 6.789383232666365`, 
 73.4704779450669`, 542.4691013882383`, 
 109.32775736858311`}}, {94991/
100000, {0.0003165983815958645`, 2.4151657749416738`*^-11, 
 0.000041392648093250344`, 5.148536966859818`*^-12, 
 1834.356885782596`, 739.3863771113772`, 9.195959681055836`, 
 99.46972019530517`, 734.4561164419442`, 
 148.07750695578338`}}, {9999/
10000, {0.0014057415265322397`, 1.0587236512295069`*^-10, 
 0.00018651445847883314`, 2.279642744932862`*^-11, 
 8400.604024058135`, 3427.9335088661996`, 42.70355313637217`, 
 454.61289195015945`, 3360.321272855625`, 687.2377176598895`}}};
tabpf = {{1/
10000, {0.007505045338308336`, 5.687643192360802`*^-10, 
 0.0015113899859115587`, 1.7976327933056706`*^-10, 
 90972.80266853518`, 56919.76997967607`, 791.9627804148239`, 
 4337.56521927994`, 34356.27729712255`, 
 12274.925357589362`}}, {5009/
100000, {0.007517000423253574`, 5.68971235625978`*^-10, 
 0.0015085450532511498`, 1.792263032381342`*^-10, 
 90662.39716548579`, 56578.568064274135`, 786.7866166520857`, 
 4327.195187616765`, 34254.43668781779`, 
 12196.876541376834`}}, {1251/
12500, {0.007497285094279013`, 5.676142632535652`*^-10, 
 0.001507980978820427`, 1.791490594621682`*^-10, 
 90704.17946156536`, 56662.02834213093`, 788.0149204440254`, 
 4327.760290680408`, 34265.25979264375`, 
 12215.573757403221`}}, {15007/
100000, {0.007520606729663031`, 5.69414999614389`*^-10, 
 0.0015131946800745221`, 1.7973239487698537`*^-10, 
 90962.36071911207`, 56798.57119584998`, 789.5085682419892`, 
 4341.823404027492`, 34368.851471479844`, 
 12240.787863069625`}}, {10003/
50000, {0.007534956153311607`, 5.698182623120455`*^-10, 
 0.001511920118749548`, 1.7934190613614568`*^-10, 
 90736.06973873514`, 56506.68293330556`, 784.8171781735601`, 
 4336.138915926086`, 34301.12126249907`, 
 12171.275738216806`}}, {5001/
20000, {0.0075493215421971035`, 5.70028376791376`*^-10, 
 0.0015093844945711333`, 1.7873715481760134`*^-10, 
 90383.39468940115`, 56089.78279329188`, 778.1679079069008`, 
 4326.066424196571`, 34191.35015081084`, 
 12072.527814841342`}}, {7501/
25000, {0.007559346036446613`, 5.697167376360261`*^-10, 
 0.0015046935563562236`, 1.7781233193625245`*^-10, 
 89873.99626619281`, 55537.96690751335`, 769.5740323241365`, 
 4309.511964302438`, 34025.831992350744`, 
 11943.982318763252`}}, {35003/
100000, {0.0075786543967993015`, 5.698671433364314`*^-10, 
 0.0015003647629570466`, 1.7685248862756692`*^-10, 
 89335.65606302141`, 54916.81564505604`, 759.8033289642185`, 
 4293.309527356858`, 33855.39888870164`, 
 11798.274391308061`}}, {20001/
50000, {0.0075980769595649315`, 5.697982991509112`*^-10, 
 0.0014944578494096171`, 1.756377444347216`*^-10, 
 88666.47341031914`, 54169.09026788119`, 748.1792521385717`, 
 4272.1015343712`, 33639.83468124321`, 
 11624.309079545961`}}, {45001/
100000, {0.007581373482561382`, 5.668915869355762`*^-10, 
 0.0014830027057789674`, 1.736955494048466`*^-10, 
 87700.66952160094`, 53248.888097033305`, 734.1037818864166`, 
 4236.625077027863`, 33311.813882116556`, 
 11412.610906961938`}}, {1/
2, {0.00759810361952814`, 5.660932500830653`*^-10, 
 0.0014726709748616607`, 1.7181146741300383`*^-10, 
 86650.18773848284`, 52149.00365964639`, 717.1690913262578`, 
 4200.898522982358`, 32964.96737313817`, 
 11158.421420387263`}}, {54999/
100000, {0.0076140686118069565`, 5.649900586358898`*^-10, 
 0.0014602609564551565`, 1.6962138368825566`*^-10, 
 85440.56869067452`, 50904.82754485654`, 698.1668926082484`, 
 4158.720478306436`, 32561.96776553715`, 
 10872.491082654176`}}, {29999/
50000, {0.007635819704719391`, 5.640215256247961`*^-10, 
 0.0014464101138064146`, 1.6719523080777206`*^-10, 
 84074.3692901383`, 49495.966486063335`, 676.662400318184`, 
 4111.13634792576`, 32106.987945156347`, 
 10548.848347807581`}}, {64997/
100000, {0.00764264913035379`, 5.616465542439801`*^-10, 
 0.001426910248645382`, 1.6405300215990911`*^-10, 
 82305.47804393024`, 47776.02066279913`, 650.669857429313`, 
 4046.095715976493`, 31505.98582764264`, 
 10156.455102638893`}}, {17499/
25000, {0.00764520342179969`, 5.586362042467936`*^-10, 
 0.001403126401175376`, 1.6036540546182663`*^-10, 
 80203.29478149791`, 45778.42862965696`, 620.6648162713186`, 
 3967.090173024876`, 30785.804797288783`, 
 9702.629783323202`}}, {14999/
20000, {0.007631121372595126`, 5.540952619863742`*^-10, 
 0.001372138533559351`, 1.5582238667123624`*^-10, 
 77589.10196891888`, 43395.37372539981`, 585.2017747292882`, 
 3865.349017014001`, 29878.084940083223`, 
 9164.690504465982`}}, {39997/
50000, {0.007580671314835792`, 5.466597470073332`*^-10, 
 0.001329306445255562`, 1.499506437140263`*^-10, 
 74170.61249281904`, 40452.42124226511`, 541.9210174537773`, 
 3726.55354606444`, 28671.114302316666`, 
 8505.72118826804`}}, {84993/
100000, {0.0074479545907734325`, 5.332435060183141`*^-10, 
 0.0012654541770267035`, 1.4182488773378088`*^-10, 
 69407.31193214256`, 36658.51969640637`, 487.0050902919086`, 
 3523.2275906345158`, 26954.845403196163`, 
 7665.37431733852`}}, {11249/
12500, {0.007125918037350224`, 5.068745380138482`*^-10, 
 0.001160759971702023`, 1.2949174696958833`*^-10, 
 62149.95886481915`, 31427.980823620168`, 412.8637658108704`, 
 3196.0466430440824`, 24279.53345105555`, 
 6523.166946085455`}}, {94991/
100000, {0.00621620768792871`, 4.414243684505194`*^-10, 
 0.0009512477169828894`, 1.0648561020632829`*^-10, 
 48932.64325567948`, 23168.932148421816`, 299.2527492608837`, 
 2561.7098562792708`, 19273.58590291903`, 
 4755.649537235555`}}, {9999/
10000, {0.0016754121376188324`, 1.2577301767994564`*^-10, 
 0.00022309476239336295`, 2.7147993630791598`*^-11, 
 10089.517006832732`, 4129.834097981659`, 51.47531997316559`, 
 545.7112127797949`, 4034.8603795789195`, 828.2458095852012`}}};
taumX = Interpolation[tabmf, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
taupX = Interpolation[tabpf, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
$min\[Tau]l = -90;
\[Epsilon]reg2 = 1/10^4;
$integralprecision = 3;
$intprec = 15;
$MaxPointsM = Automatic;
Tol[x_] := If[x < $min\[Tau]l, $min\[Tau]l, x];
fy[y_]:=y/Sqrt[1-y^2];
Q0int[y_?NumericQ] := fy[y]*((Exp[Map[Tol, -taumX[y]]] + Exp[Map[Tol, -taupX[y]]])/2);
Q0i := NIntegrate[Q0int[y], {y, \[Epsilon]reg2, 1 - \[Epsilon]reg2}, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", PrecisionGoal -> $integralprecision, AccuracyGoal -> $integralprecision, WorkingPrecision -> $intprec, MaxPoints -> $MaxPointsM];

In this specific example, the function Q0int can be plotted but Q0i returns error.

Please provide runnable code!

I added a runnable example.

Q0int[]returns a list (of results), is this intended?.

modified
The interpolation functions return a list of values, that's why Q0int[] returns a list too!
I don't know why plot and integration fails but will present a workaround which seem to work
Try
taumX = Interpolation[tabmf, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
taupX = Interpolation[tabpf, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
$min\[Tau]l = -90;
\[Epsilon]reg2 = 1/10^4;
$integralprecision = 3;
$intprec = 15;
$MaxPointsM = Automatic;
Tol[x_] := If[x < $min\[Tau]l, $min\[Tau]l, x];
fy[y_] := y/Sqrt[1 - y^2];

Instead of definition Q0int[y] we introduce an index version
q0int[y_?NumericQ, i_] := fy[y]*((Exp[ Tol[-taumX[y][[i]]]] +Exp[Tol[-taupX[y][[i]]]])/2);    (* i: list index *) 

Plot:
Table[Plot[
   Evaluate[ q0int[y, i]  ], {y, \[Epsilon]reg2, 1 - \[Epsilon]reg2 },
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> RandomColor[]] // Quiet, {i, 1, 
  10}]  


Integration:
Table[NIntegrate[
   q0int[y, i], {y, \[Epsilon]reg2, 1 - \[Epsilon]reg2} ], {i, 1, 
   10}] // Quiet
(*{0.982634, 0.985858, 0.985305, 0.985858, 8.07813*10^-40, 
8.07813*10^-40, 0.00508992, 6.85627*10^-17, 8.07813*10^-40, 
4.87195*10^-24}*)

Hope it helps!

Interesting. I’ll play with it tomorrow. I indeed need all the values in the list, not just the first. I’m not sure which is the piece of code that causes problems at this point. Tol was introduced after first noticing the problem, it didnt solve it but kept it there.

thanks, this indeed solves the issue!

Ok, I reproduced this problem in a simpler environment. It looks like that any interpolation of a function that returns a list gives problems. At least with my version 13.3:
dataX = Table[{n, {n, 2 n}}, {n, 0, 10}];
dataF = Interpolation[dataX, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
dataFi[x_?NumericQ, i_] := dataF[x][[i]];
Now I get:
Plot[dataF[x], {x, 0, 10}]
works without issues
NIntegrate[dataF[x], {x, 0, 10}]
Returns error, integrand non numerical
NIntegrate[Table[dataFi[x, i], {i, 1, 2}], {x, 0, 10}]
Works but returns multiple Part::partw errors

Table[NIntegrate[dataFi[x, i], {x, 0, 10}], {i, 1, 2}]
works but returns a single Part::partw error
I am pretty sure numerical integration of functions returning lists used to work in previous versions...is this a bug?
If I use dataX = Table[{n, n}, {n, 0, 10}]; there is no problem using NIntegrate on the interpolated function. This seems some problem related to lists only.
